# CollectionViewController cell selection - empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my CustomCollectionViewController class I have a method which detects selection of the cell:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{   
    UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Category selected" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.item + 1] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [messageAlert show];
}
```

which works well.

But if I changed this method to simple:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLevelsSegue" sender:self];
}
```

it crashes with an error:

'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'.

I have created a segue with showLevelsSegue identifier in my storyboard. I have simple structure: Navigation controller -> CustomCollectionViewController -> ViewController.

Can anyone help me?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { 
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showLevelsSegue"]) { 
         UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)sender;
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];   
         DataManager *sharedManager = [DataManager sharedManager];
         sharedManager.categoryId = indexPath.row; 
     } 
}
```

EDIT 2 - according to @Larme answer, it didnt solve the problem yet

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showLevelsSegue"]) {
        NSArray *arrayOfIndexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [arrayOfIndexPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        DataManager *sharedManager = [DataManager sharedManager];

        sharedManager.categoryId = selectedIndexPath.row;
    }
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLevelsSegue" sender:nil];
}
```

Comment: Why `sender:self`? What's in `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: what should I put instead of sender:self ?

Comment: Consider taking code out of your comment and instead make an edit to your post for readability purposes.

Comment: Well, `(UICollectionViewCell *)sender; `: sender if your object (self: ViewController ?), not the cell.

Comment: ok, I moved code of prepareForSegue from comment into edited post

Comment: Where is the exception being triggered? 
Try setting a breakpoints inside didSelectItemAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue and let us know where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In your `CustomCollectionViewController`:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLevelsSegue" sender:self];
```

`self` is an instance of `CustomCollectionViewController` class.

So when you do this:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)sender;
```

You're wrong, except if `CustomCollectionViewController` inherits from `UICollectionViewCell`, but I clearly doubt it.

So, there are a few ways to do it:

• Since you seems to trigger the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender` with `showLevelSegue`, you can retrieve inside it the `UICollectionViewCell` selected with

```
NSArray *arrayOfIndexPaths = [yourCollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
NSIndexPath selectedIndexPath = [arrayOfIndexPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

And no need do pass `self` as a parameter, send just `nil`: `[ZzZ sender:nil];`

• Or you could send the `NSIndexPath` there:
`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLevelsSegue" sender:indexPath];`
And retrieve it:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
```

Comment: I changed the code in EDIT 2 according to your post. Is that exactly what you meant?

Comment: I proposed 2 different solutions (each on starting with a bullet point: •). You mixed them, that's normal you have an error.

Comment: really? I think not, i didnt use second solution, well i think so

Comment: you mean i should comment whole didSelectItemAtIndexPath method?

Comment: commenting that method didnt change anything unfortunately

Comment: No. You should put `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLevelsSegue" sender:indexPath];`instead.